# Holy Grail 3 Columns Full Height Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a three columns layout with percentage width. After searching google and reading some articles I came to know this layout is a part of [Holy Grail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_%28web_design%29) web-design. I have taken the example given in this website: [The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) and modified the width as I need 20% width for left and right column. But in this layout doesn't cover the 100% height. The height of this layout is equals to the maximum height of three columns. Use of `min-height:100%` or `height:100%` doesn't work for this. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/BNjU5/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/BNjU5/2/)

Just set height 100% to html,body:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

And also give inner three columns 100% height;

```
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;         
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

height:100% of nothing gives nothing.

you need elements width an height fixed in css so childs can inherit its value to calculate % of it :

```
html, body, .colmask, .colmid, .colleft
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

CSS = **Cascaded** Style Sheet :)
DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/BNjU5/1/